# Is my proof of this fact about pi correct?

Tags: solution-verification, irrational-numbers, pi

I recently have thought of a proof but I can’t tell if it is correct or not.
The proof is of $n \pi$ being irrational if n is an integer and non zero. The proof is below:

We assume that $n \pi$ is not irrational, thus meaning that $n \pi \in \mathbb Q$. Since $\sin(x)$ is an irrational number if x $\in \mathbb Q$ we can logically assume that $\sin(n \pi)$ is then irrational. But as we all know,
$\sin(n \pi)$ = 0. QED

I have a lot of doubts about the proof being correct especially because of the fact that the proof seems to simple and that am usually terrible with proofs. Can someone please tell me if the proof is correct or incorrect? And if it is incorrect, (which it probably is) can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: I dont like the sentence that $\sin(x)$ is irrational if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ because $x=0$ gives a counter example. Also it seems a bit of difficult to prove this statement? Are you allowed to use the fact that $\pi$ is irrational? If so then the whole proof could be much simpler :)

Comment: Your proof looks right. Just exclude $x=0$ from the claim that $\sin x$ is an irrational number. The fact about $\sin$ that you are using: could it be that the proof of that needs that $\pi$ is irrational?

Comment: I found that fact on Wikipedia which stated that $\sin (x)$ is transcendental for any non zero algebraic number X. I had put in the proof that n in non zero so $n \pi$ cannot be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof isn't *wrong* but it depends on the following prior result:

> If $x$ is a nonzero rational number then $\sin x$ is irrational.

(You stated it without the "nonzero" condition, which makes it false, but with that correction it's true, and even more is true: if $x$ is a nonzero rational number then $\sin x$ is *transcendental*.) That's true, but it's just as difficult to prove as the irrationality of $\pi$. In fact, I think the only known proofs are more difficult than the easiest proofs that $\pi$ is irrational.

(There's an easier theorem -- "Niven's theorem" -- which is about when $r$ and $\sin r\pi$ are both rational. But what you need is something different.)

Comment: Thanks, I truly thought that my proof was wrong because am usually quite bad with proofs. And I should have put the non zero correction in my proof and the transcendental thing as well. I didn’t think I had to prove the fact $\sin (x)$ is irrational for any non zero rational number though since it had already been proven, but I should have definitely clarified. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, the irrationality of $\pi$ has also already been proven! So if you're happy appealing to already-known results, you just say: "Theorem: $\pi$ is irrational. Proof: It is well known that $\pi$ is irrational, QED." :-)

Comment: Yea I could do that. But I wanted to find an alternative proof that was actually more clever and creative than simply using one of the most known results in mathematics, though you could argue this proof is probably not very clever or creative.